# Radio Button same name, no selection and submit

Tags: javascript, php, html

when all radio button is same name(Which mean user only allow to select one and must select one). If I want to do all Radiobutton is same name and allow user dint select anything and submit. then the result is 0 and store to database is that possible?

OR

I can create a default radiobutton which value = 0 and hidden it?
how do I do it?

```
echo "<form name='myfm' method='post' action='quizz.php' id='myfm' onSubmit='return test()'>";
echo "<table width=100%> <tr> <td width=30>&nbsp;<td> <table border=0>";
$n=$_SESSION[qn]+1;
echo "<tR><td><span class=que style=font-size:20px>Que ". $n .": $row[2]</style>";
echo "<tr><td class=style8 style=font-size:20px><input type=radio name=ans value=1> $row[3]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8 style=font-size:20px><input type=radio name=ans value=2> $row[4]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8 style=font-size:20px><input type=radio name=ans value=3> $row[5]";
echo "<tr><td class=style8 style=font-size:20px><input type=radio name=ans value=4> $row[6]";

if($_SESSION[qn]<mysqli_num_rows($rs)-1)
echo "<br><br><tr><td><input type=submit class='btn btn-success' name=submit value='Next Question'></form>";
else
echo "<br><br><tr><td><input type=submit name=submit class='btn btn-danger' value='Get Result' id='getrr'></form>";
```

Comment: Please replace the PHP source with example HTML output, you're much more likely to get help that way.

Comment: @ChrisG Just found the answer after posted the question, sorry about the PHP source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can create a default radiobutton which value = 0 and hidden it?

Yes, use the `hidden` attribute to hide it and `checked` to select it as the default.

```html
<input type=radio name=ans value=0 hidden checked>
<input type=radio name=ans value=1>Option 1
<input type=radio name=ans value=2>Option 2
<input type=radio name=ans value=3>Option 3
<input type=radio name=ans value=4>Option 4
```

However this isn't a perfect solution because a user will be forced to select at least one **once he has selected any**.
Because of this I'ld advise you to just make it another visible option like this:

```html
<input type=radio name=ans value=0 checked>None
<input type=radio name=ans value=1>Option 1
<input type=radio name=ans value=2>Option 2
<input type=radio name=ans value=3>Option 3
<input type=radio name=ans value=4>Option 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just add display:none, make change of the value to 0 and checked.
EXAMPLE:
`echo "<tr><td class=style8 style=display:none><input type=radio name=ans value=0 checked>";`

Comment: **This solution has a flaw**. If the user selects any option he won't be able to go back to having selected none.